# Correct usage of destructuring-bind

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm experimenting with destructuring-bind as follows:

```
(destructuring-bind
           (a  b) '(1  2) (list a b)))
```

When I evaluate this in the REPL I get:

```
READ from #1=#<INPUT STRING-INPUT-STREAM>: an object cannot start with #\)
   [Condition of type SYSTEM::SIMPLE-READER-ERROR]
```

I expected the result to be

```
(1 2)
```

The error doesn't mean anything to me, in the context of the code above.

I realise that I'm just binding a simple list of arguments, rather than a tree, but I still expecteded this to work. Any clues as to where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the extra ) on the end. Works fine.

Comment: Groan, how embarrassing. Thanks! At least I now know how to interpret that error msg in future.

Answer (score 5):

While we are at it, the usual formatting is:

```
(destructuring-bind (a b)
    '(1 2)
  (list a b))
```

It also makes it easier to see how the parentheses match. Generally the editor will also help. Placing the cursor after a closing parenthesis should highlight the corresponding opening parenthesis. Also note that all self-respecting Lisp-syntax-capable editors have a command to find non-matching parentheses.

Comment: I knew someone would comment on that ;-)

Comment: I'm using Emacs/Slime, which highlights the brackets & I thought I had checked they all matched up, but I clearly wasn't being to carefull, 100 lashings for my sins ;-) To add to my lack of with-it-ness - I even chose to ignore the huge hint the SO code editor was giving me by highlighting the code I pasted in, in red!